# Is it possible to pull information out a link from an article form for example the verge

Tags: php, xml, rss, xml-parsing, simplepie

I am trying to make something where you put in a link from an article and it puts out the article so the title, description , ... Is that possible, i think there is a way because some websites do it. And i think it's only  compatible with websites that an rss reader can read. Can somebody help me or give me a little help on how to do it with simple pie for example.

Comment: Is this article on your server or someone else's?

Comment: This is a very broadly phrased question. Is there some specific step you're stuck on?

Comment: cURL the data and parse it using DOMDocument. There's your info :)

Comment: Please be more precise, where what is stored. This kind of question can't really be answered.

Comment: the article comes from a blog. It actually the same thing as the reader function in safari. And you can copy the url in a web app and the web app will display it clean. Just like the reader function on safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reason why RSS exists - A way to read information in a standardized way.
In the pre html5-era every web-developer is more or less inventing his own format, because xhtml, html4 didn't have the right semantic elements for this.

A few examples:

```
<div class="article">
   <h1>Article</h1>
   <p>Content Content Content Content Content</p>
</div>

<div class="article">
   <span class="arcticleHeader">Article</span>
   <div class="left">Content Content Content Content Content</div>
</div>
```

with html5 it is different.
there are much more semantic elements like `<article>`, `<header>`, `<footer>`.

but you can still not know, how the content is actually structured.

you should use, a well defined format for this like [RSS](http://feed2.w3.org/docs/rss2.html), [ATOM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287), [RDF](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework).
[Wikipedia describes this problem very well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS)

> A standardized XML file format allows the information to be published once and viewed by many different programs.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you get the content out a url from an article which has <article> tag's in it. There has to be some javascript or php code required. And i can't an example from that  anywhere. Services like digg use this i think.

Comment: [parsing rss in php](http://rssphp.net/) and [php xml parser](http://php.net/manual/de/book.xml.php)